# An FBML skeleton/sandbox page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

Does anyone know where I could find a decent skeleton page or example for creating an all-FBML Facebook app?  I've looked all over the official wiki and done a bunch of searches, but I can't find anything reliable.  Most of the examples in the wiki are either outdated, broken or oversimplistic.  I can do 'Hello World' - now I need the rest.

For example, do I need to use the  tag to enclose all my FBML?  Where do I use  - only in iframes?  How and when do I use profile.setFBML?

I realize the competition is fierce, but there has to be some decent resources out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML is being deprecated (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/), you should look into using the Javascript SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) wrapper for the Graph API.

Also, some of the core things done with FBML now can be done in HTML social plugins.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Sample apps are usually distributed with the client library (such as the .NET or RoR libraries).

Are you really trying to build an app entirely in FBML with no backend?

Additional information on what you are trying to achieve would be beneficial to helping you.